# Error: The requested address '/admin/hear_aboutus' was not found on this server. | cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I've deleted my original question regarding this and reposted to make this question more clear

I have two controllers

1) **interests_controller.php**

```
class InterestsController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Interests';

    function admin_index() 

        $this->pageTitle = __l('Interests');
        $this->Interest->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('Interests', $this->paginate());
    }
```

2) **hear_aboutus_controller.php**

```
class HearAboutusController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'HearAboutus';

    function admin_index() 
    {
        $this->pageTitle = __l('Where did you hear of us?');
        $this->HearAboutus->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('HearAboutus', $this->paginate());
    }
```

They are called the following ways

```
1) admin/interests
2) admin/hear_aboutus
```

Now the Interest Controller renders all prefectly but when I call the Hear about us I get Controller not found and **admin/hear_aboutus' was not found on this server.**

My two Model look like this

1) **interest.php**

```
class Interest extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Interest';
```

2) **hear_aboutu.php**

```
class HearAboutu extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'HearAboutu';

    var $useTable="hear_about_us";
```

The views are

```
1) interests/admin_index.ctp
2) hear_aboutus/admin_index.ctp
```

I'm honestly not sure what I'm doing wrong here since both these are exactly the same kust dirrerent naming conventions and only interest works? When I set debug mode to two I get Controller not found in the title and then a blank page

Comment: Try to change you controller name to "ThoughtsController" and your model to "Thought". Also, rename your table to "thoughts" (you also have to change sequences names and other stuff; but do it only if this test works). If the error vanish, maybe the inflector can't handle the name you previously gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using a noun for the table (referrals instead of hear_aboutus)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually creating models, views and controllers, CakePHP can help you make them

In your command prompt or console go to your CakePHP directory, and type in the following commands:

- Models: .\bin\cake bake model HearAboutus
- Controller: .\bin\cake bake controller HearAboutus
- Template: .\bin\cake bake template HearAboutus